# Cordova: How to implement app to app calling?

Tags: cordova

I am on the way to complete my cordova based mobile application. I want to add a functionality of app to app calling in it. I havent found any plugin or extension in cordova to implement it. Anyone have experience with app to app calling or have implemented it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible for Android through [this Plugin](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp). For iOS not possible.

**For iOS 9 now it is possible to link directly into another application. But till now, there are not enough information on how this will work and how this will work with cordova.**